# How can one install Slackware current from its DVD iso image?

Tags: system-installation, slackware

I would like to install Slackware current, the [official installation instructions](https://docs.slackware.com/slackware:current) involve using slackpkg from an existing Slackware installation, but I downloaded the live ISO of Slackware current and was hoping it was possible to install it using it. The usual procedure of installing Slackware from a live session, namely partitioning the disks and create relevant file systems, then running the `setup` command doesn't work on Slackware current as the `setup` command doesn't exist.

Comment: Try asking over at Linux Questions https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/
That's where Pat himself and folks like Alien Bob hang out. If they can't answer your question, no one can.

Answer (score 2):

BH2017,

Your steps were (almost) correct.  You need the Slackware-current and not the Slackware-current Live ISO.  First, check the date on "FILELIST.TXT" on this page:  https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/slackware/slackware64-current/
I suggest that you check if the date matches the one for the next two pages in order to download the latest version.

The Slackware-current ISO can be found here:  http://bear.alienbase.nl/mirrors/slackware/slackware64-current-iso/

Alternatively, you can download the ISO here:
http://slackware.uk/people/alien-current-iso/slackware-current-iso/

Beware that the latest version of Slackware-current comes with xorg-server 1.20.0, which causes any DisplayLink based docking station to stop working, as mentioned here:  https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1181623-displaylink-ubuntu-driver-after-recent-x-upgrades

That ISO does contain the "setup" package and can be installed as any other version of Slackware

Answer (score 2):

codesforu,

If you read my post from June 5, 2018, you can find the ISO file:

The Slackware-current ISO can be found here: http://bear.alienbase.nl/mirrors/slackware/slackware64-current-iso/

There is no need to reinvent the wheel or rsync the whole mirror and then create the ISO file

Answer (score 1):

It is June 2019 now. 
And I got my own solution done here: https://github.com/codesforu/slackware64-current-iso

I faced with a problem when try to install the latest release available now, Slackware 14.2 , on a computer with 8th Intel CPU using "slackware64-14.2-install-dvd.iso", and it is hardly bootable. The reason is Slackware 14.2 uses an out-dated Linux kernel (4.4.14) which can hardly boot on new Intel CPUs (since 7th or 8th, not sure for which generation exactly), and I want to install Slackware-current with a newer kernel (4.19.52).

Those methods mentioned with "installing Slackware 14.2 first" or  "installing with Alien Bob's release or using his script" is not really installing the real slackware-current.
After searching around I found nothing useful but an old post contains a clue. [Slackware-current ISO(s)](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/slackware-current-iso-s-192566/) It was 2004 when Slackware still had official ISO release on the -current branch.
The clue leads me to another clue found in the Slackware source tree 
[/slackware/slackware64-current/isolinux/README.TXT](https://mirror.slackbuilds.org/slackware/slackware64-current/isolinux/README.TXT)  and the Slackware mirroring guildlines [Mirroring Guidelines](https://mirrors.slackware.com/guidelines/).

The solution is:
 1. to get a copy of "mirror.slackbuilds.org/slackware/slackware64-current/" with sync or any other avaliable tool, and
 2. to generate an ISO image with the command described in the "README.TXT"

To star my github repository mentioned above is also welcome, if you find my solution helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First install Slackware 14.2 (the latest stable version). Download or order from http://www.slackware.com/getslack/

If you need help installing the latest stable version, read though http://www.slackware.com/install/

Once you've got 14.2 installed, follow the instructions at the link you posted under [Tracking the Current Branch](https://docs.slackware.com/slackware:current#tracking_the_current_branch).
Crucially:

> edit the `/etc/slackpkg/mirrors` file and comment out the mirror pointing to your stable version and uncomment one of the mirrors pointing to the current branch

and

> run the command (as root) `slackpkg update`

Comment: I knew about this method, didn't you read my question? I did not follow it because I wanted to install from the Slackware current live ISO. Therefore I cannot accept this answer as it doesn't answer my question at all.